# Lots of confusion about declaration files

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript does not have support for many WebGL 2 functions and interfaces, like `createVertexArray()`. Because of this, I want to write a declaration file that wraps the function so that the compiler won't throw a fit. To do this I have written a javascript file that contains the unsupported functions:

```
function createVertexArray(glContext) {
    return glContext.createVertexArray();
}
// a bunch more
```

I now need to create a Typescript declaration file for these functions. As I understand it, when you ask typescript to load a module, it looks at the directory for an index.d.ts file. There you have to define the functions and interfaces used in your javascript file. This is what I have so far:

```
declare module Webgl2 {
    export interface WebGLVertexArrayObject {}
    export function createVertexArray(glContext: WebGLRenderingContext):WebGLVertexArrayObject;
    export function deleteVertexArray(glContext: WebGLRenderingContext, vertexArray: WebGLVertexArrayObject):void;
    export function isVertexArray(glContext: WebGLRenderingContext, vertexArray: WebGLVertexArrayObject):boolean;
    export function bindVertexArray(glContext: WebGLRenderingContext, vertexArray: WebGLVertexArrayObject):void;
}

export = Webgl2;
```

However, I need help with the following:

1. How do I load the module in the rest of my typescript application?
2. Is the javascript file loaded automatically or do I have to do that manually when the page is served?
3. In my javascript file do I have to declare the functions as the module exports?
4. In my javascript file do I have to declare the interface that `createVertexArray()` returns?

I have put both files on pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/M70uqcMA).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How do you suggest I should have asked the question?

Comment: First of all I do recommend you to do some research on the Internet. Do you really think you are the first man on earth trying to import/export a module?

Comment: I did look around especially at the guide on the typescript website. I didn't understand some of it though, so I came here to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody has been working on this for some time already. You can find the `WebGL2.d.ts` file [here](https://github.com/MaxGraey/WebGL2-TypeScript/blob/master/WebGL2.d.ts).

Then you can import using the `"files"` field in the `tsconfig.json` file as shown [here](https://github.com/MaxGraey/WebGL2-TypeScript/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L11-L14).

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "types": [],
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "lib": ["ES2015", "ES2017.SharedMemory", "DOM"]
    },
    "files": [
        "Misc.d.ts",
        "WebGL2.d.ts"
    ]
}
```